# Statically Loading a .txt File

Tags: java, file, load

I understand that this question has been asked often before, and yet none of the other answers have worked for me. I am trying to statically load a .txt file in. It works wile inside the compiler (Eclipse) but after I export I get a FileNotFound exception.

I need a method that will take in a file path and load that .txt file statically, and return that file as a String. I think I have to do something with `loadRecourceAsStream()` but I am not sure.

Here is how I am loading it now:

```
public static String getFilePath(String path) {

    String line = null;
    String file = "";

    try {

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            file = file + line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file " + path + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}
```

Here are some other things I have tried. They all work in the compiler but not after exporting:

```
public static String loadFileAsString(String path){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
        br.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

And:

```
public static String getFile(String path) {
    Scanner controlBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
    controlBoard = new Scanner(Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(path));

    String file = controlBoard.nextLine();
    file += "\n" + controlBoard.nextLine();
    file += "\n" + controlBoard.nextLine();

    return file;

}
```

And:

```
 public static String getFile(String path) {
    System.out.println("test");
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Have you checked the created `.jar` ? Does it contain the file you try to access ? In which folder inside the jar ? This needs to match your code when you try to use getResourceAsStream

Comment: What "doesn't work after exporting"?  What exceptions and/or errors are you getting?  "Doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information for anyone to help you without taking a wild guess.  "Any ideas on what I should do?"  Yes.  First provide details on what's not working.

Comment: @Andrew Henle As I said, a FileNotFoundException

Comment: @Marged it is inside it is at NameOfJar.jar/maps/Level1.txt. Doing /maps/Level1.txt for a path still results in the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem has to be related in how you are running your program when exported as I have taken your code, created a jar, run it and it worked without changing a single line. Well, I have added a main function to be able to run it. I add the code just in case but you will see that the code is the same.

```
package com.iseji.app.main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println(getFilePath(args[0]));
}

public static String getFilePath(String path) {

    String line = null;
    String file = "";

    try {

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            file = file + line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file " + path + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}
}
```

So the question is how have you imported the file into a jar. You can really just use the "Export to" functionality of your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ or whatever). On the other hand I recommend you to use a life-cycle software framework like maven or gradle. Just as an example I show the gradle file that I use to create the jar (but as I say, this is not really important)

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.iseji.app.main.Main'
    }
}
```

Anyway how you export your code to a jar, the key is how the Manifest file looks like. You have to be sure that it indicates which is the main class. Verify that it is similar to:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.iseji.app.main.Main
```

In such a way you will be able to run it as normally passing as a parameter the file to read

```
java -jar ReadingFile-1.0.jar ../../src/main/resources/sample.txt
```

As I said at the beginning your code is fine. Just double check how you are exporting the code and running it

Comment: My manifest file has this one line: Main-Class: main.Main. I am exporting using the basic eclipse Export>executable jar.  The location of my txt file is  maps.Level1.  I do have some images that I have managed to load in like this: `ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path));` I have tried changing my path to \maps\Level1.txt and .\maps\Level1.txt. I do not know what is wrong with the export.

Comment: It has to point to your class in an unequivocal way. If your Main class is into a main package is fine (in my case it was into a com.iseji.app.main package).

Comment: But how do you specify the path when running the jar?

Comment: What do you mean, specify the path when running the jar? You mean like \maps\Level1.txt?

Comment: I mean how you provide the place where the txt is. If you see in my example I run by "java -jar ReadingFile-1.0.jar ../../src/main/resources/sample.txt

The ../../src/main/resources/sample.txt is the relative position of the txt file from where the jar file is. 

I am asking because in function of the error you get (FileNotFound exception) looks like you are not pointing to the place where the txt is.

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: If you run java -jar NameOfYourJar.jar /maps/Level1.txt you have to be sure that the txt your file are in the following tree structure:
/NameOfYourJar.jar
/maps
----/Level1.txt

By the way, double check if you need slash or backslash (/ or \)

Comment: The relative position is \maps\Level1.txt. However, putting this path in gets the same error. Or at least, the whole thing is in the jar and maps is a folder in the jar. Just as /main/Main.class.

Comment: How do I know if I need a slash or backslash? Also, hold on let my try with the Level1 just in the NameOfJar.jar, no folders or anything

Comment: To double check that it is a problem of specifying the path make a quick test. Put the txt file and the jar file in the same directory and run it by "java -jar NameOfYourJar.jar Level1.txt

Comment: Doing java -jar NameOfJar.jar gives a FileNotFound error. Doing java -jar NameOfJar.txt Level1 gives Error: Unable to access jarfile NameOfJar.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94509/discussion-between-calvin-and-iseji).